# Asynchronous function not terminating

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions, firebase-admin

I am writing an async function `async_create_user`, used for my firebase HTTPS function `create_user` of the form in `index.js`.

**index.js**

```
exports.create_user = functions.https.onCall(async_create_user);
```

I am testing them all in a single file `user.js` like this, and running `node user.js` 
The code gets the expected behaviour of creating the User documents in my database, but my intention for this function is also to terminate so that I can test it with a sequence of other functions. May I know if there is an implementation to let it terminate.

```
const { admin, db } = require("../util/admin");
//const db = admin.firestore();
//const admin = require('firebase-admin');
//admin.initializeApp(config);

const config = require("../util/config");
const { uuid } = require("uuidv4");

const {
  success_response,
  error_response
} = require("../util/validators");

const firebase = require("firebase");
firebase.initializeApp(config);

const {
  validateSignupData,
  validateLoginData,
  reduceUserDetails,
} = require("../util/validators");



exports.async_create_user = async function(data, context) {
  // Perform Authentication Checks
  try {
    const userRecord = await admin.auth().createUser({
      displayName: data.displayName,
      email: data.email,
      emailVerified: true,
      password: data.password,
      disabled: false
    });

    await admin.auth().setCustomUserClaims(userRecord.uid, {user_basic: true})

    //data required for the personal?
    const PrivateUser = {
      display_name: data.displayName,
      email: data.email,
      notification_ids: [],
      saved_posts: [],
      last_updated: admin.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp()
    };

    const noImg = "no-img.png";

    //sets default profile image to be the empty image
    const PublicUser = {
      profile_image:
        {
          url: "some url",
          uid: userRecord.uid
        }
    }

    await db
      .collection("users_private")
      .doc(userRecord.uid)
      .set(PrivateUser);

    await db
      .collection("users_public")
      .doc(userRecord.uid)
      .set(PublicUser);

    console.log(userRecord.uid);
    return success_response();

  } catch (error) {
    console.log("Error in creation of user account", error);
    return error_response(error);
  }
}


const mockUser =     {
  displayName: "Mallory",
  email: "mallory@example.org",
  password: "123456",

  disabled: false,
  emailVerified: true
}

exports.async_create_user(mockUser);
```

Comment: "*I am trying to run a continuous script, so I need this to terminate.*" - I don't know what this means.  Please edit the question to explain what you're trying to accomplish in more detail.

Answer (score -1):

I have written a library called [rubico](https://github.rubico.land) that removes a lot of cruft surrounding Promises. The result is simpler code; rubico handles asynchronous termination so you don't have to.

```js
const { pipe, fork, get, tap, tryCatch } = require('rubico')

const setCustomUserClaims = uid =>
  admin.auth().setCustomUserClaims(uid, { user_basic: true })

const getServerTimestamp = () => admin.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp()

const createPrivateUser = ({ uid, PrivateUser }) =>
  db.collection('users_private').doc(uid).set(PrivateUser)

const createPublicUser = ({ uid, PublicUser }) =>
  db.collection('users_public').doc(uid).set(PrivateUser)

const createUser = pipe([
  fork({
    displayName: get('displayName'), // input => input.displayName
    email: get('email'), // input => input.email
    emailVerified: () => true, // () => true
    password: get('password'), // input => input.password
    disabled: () => false, // () => false
  }), // { displayName, email, password } => { displayName, email, emailVerified, password, disabled } === userPreRecord
  admin.auth().createUser, // userPreRecord => userRecord
  tap(pipe([get('uid'), setCustomUserClaims])), // setCustomUserClaims with uid but don't care about the return
  fork({
    uid: get('uid'), // userRecord => userRecord.uid
    PrivateUser: fork({
      display_name: get('displayName'), // userRecord => userRecord.displayName
      email: get('email'), // userRecord => userRecord.email
      notification_ids: () => [],
      saved_posts: () => [],
      last_updated: getServerTimestamp,
    }),
    PublicUser: fork({
      profile_image: fork({
        url: () => 'no-img.png',
        uid: get('uid'), // userRecord => userRecord.uid
      }),
    }),
  }),
  tap(fork([ // tap: run input through the following fork of functions and discard return.
    createPrivateUser, // userRecord => createPrivateUser(userRecord)
    createPublicUser, // userRecord => createPublicUser(userRecord)
  ])),
])

exports.async_create_user = tryCatch( // try pipe([createUser, success_response]), catch with err => {...}
  pipe([createUser, success_response]),
  err => {
    console.log("Error in creation of user account", err);
    error_response(err);
  },
)
```

I've included comments in my example, but to really make sense of the code above, I recommend you read the [intuition](https://github.rubico.land#introduction), then the [docs](https://github.rubico.land#documentation)